# Facebook SDK for Windows Phone: InvalidCastException when calling FacebookSessionClient.LoginAsync(permissions);

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, facebook-c#-sdk

- I'm using the Facebook SDK for Windows Phone.
- I have created a Facebook app, enabled the option "Website with Facebook Login" and have assigned the appID in the code.
- When I execute the code the Facebook app I've created appears in the "Your Apps" section on Facebook, but then errors out with an InvalidCastException.
- The version of the Facebook client that I'm using is 0.3.0.0.

This line of code throws an InvalidCastException:

```
session = await App.FacebookSessionClient.LoginAsync("user_about_me,read_stream");
```

Following is the stacktrace:

```
at Facebook.Client.FacebookSessionClient.<LoginAsync>d__d.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.MoveNextRunner.Run()
at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.<>c__DisplayClassa.<OnCompletedInternal>b__1(Object state)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(RuntimeMethodInfo rtmi, Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isBinderDefault, Assembly caller, Boolean verifyAccess, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeOne(Object[] args)
at System.MulticastDelegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
at System.Delegate.DynamicInvoke(Object[] args)
at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Dispatch(DispatcherPriority priority)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.OnInvoke(Object context)
at System.Windows.Hosting.CallbackCookie.Invoke(Object[] args)
at System.Windows.Hosting.DelegateWrapper.InternalInvoke(Object[] args)
at System.Windows.RuntimeHost.ManagedHost.InvokeDelegate(IntPtr pHandle, Int32 nParamCount, ScriptParam[] pParams, ScriptParam& pResult)
```

Comment: This is a bug. More info at at https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-winclient-sdk/issues/13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is now fixed in 0.4.0 release of the SDK. Please get the latest nuget package and try again.

Thanks